# custom initiation and edit task forms in sequential workflow

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How to set custom initiation and edit task forms in SharePoint 2010 sequential workflows. Please post me with awesome links with best practices. Thanks a lot. Cheers!!!.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/03/30/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-sequential-workflow-with-a-custom-task-form-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010-part-2-of-2/) provide a good example how to create custom workflow with custom task form
and for [initiation form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231590.aspx)